# How to set up a file that works only on a particular computer

Tags: windows, copy, registry

I need to protect a file or folder and prevent it from being copied. I mean, when users try to copy it on external drive or send the file via email - it won't work on theirs machines.

Windows 7 and XP are my targets.

Comment: What do you mean "won't work"?  What type of file?  Is this some kind of executable file?  What exactly are you expecting if someone copies it?  That they can't open it in any application, including a text editor?  And if you're including folders in this question, do you mean to say that a copied folder couldn't be opened on another system?  I think what you're asking is probably impossible, but you need to be more clear.

Comment: I have one html file, which is an application created for offline use. Like quiz. So, I need to make this html file works only on several computers, but do not allow users to copy it on for example their own laptops etc.

Comment: This is a question for the SuperUser forum, not StackOverflow.  There may be some Windows permissions or some other way to lock down Windows  user accounts so they can't copy/paste a file.  But this is not a programming related question.

Comment: Ok then, I thought this is trivial question, but I will try my luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do so would make the file a system file; if it doesn't need to be edited make system32 the owner of the file. When you do that' it's almost invisible so the user won't know it exists....Unfortunately, it's not possible to prevent copying of a file if it's executable.

Comment: Like I said above, it is html quiz that should work on several local machines and I would @install@ it there. How could I prevent users to copy the entire folder with this html file and play this quiz on their computers at home?